# Unable to add action to dynamically created button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I created one button dynamically in JavaScript and I am unable to set action for that button..

```
var but = document.createElement("input");
but.type = "button"
but.value = "NewButton";
but.onClick = check();
var newElement = document.getElementById("addButton"); //span element id
newElement.appendChild(but);
```

The function 'check()' is not called when button is clicked

Comment: What is returned by `check()`? If you want check to be invoked upon a button click, remove the parenthesis: `but.onClick = check;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code. The first is that the event is not capitalized, the second is that you want to assign the event to the function rather than the results of the function. It should look like:

```
but.onclick = check;
```

This will actually assign the event to the address of the function rather than the expected result of the function (which would do nothing).

Answer (score 1):

`check()` executes the function, and will assign whatever that function returns to but.onClick. To assign the function to an event, specify it by name (without the parens).

Answer (score 0):

Small case `onclick`:

```
but.onclick = check();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think yours `check` function not returns function which is needed to assign as callback for onclick event, then

```
but.onclick = check;
```

for example in case:

```
var check = function() {   
     return function(){
        /* some logic eg. dependent of arguments 'parent' function' */  
    }  }
//works
but.onclick = check('somethingImportant');
```

All right,  but there is a problem if you wanted to assign several callbacks for these event :)
It would be better if you know about `addEventListener` / `attachEvent`

```
but.addEventListener( 'click', check,true );
but.addEventListener( 'click', check2,true );
```

Afterwards if needed use `removeEventLister` or `detachEvent` to detach function(s);

However - try to play with jquery :)

```
var check = function(){/* do something */};
        $('#addButton').append(
           $('<input type="button" value="New Button"/>') 
        ).click( check );​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

or

```
    $('#addButton').append( 
           $('<input/>' ).attr( 'type', 'button' ).val( 'New Button' ) )
                .click( function(){ /* do something */ } ) ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    );
```

then

```
$('#addButton').unbind(  'click' ) // unbind( 'click',check )
```

And much more posibilities to doing that :)

Comment: Thank You Abuduba for all your answers